# How to identify added and modified children after reconnecting to Zookeeper?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

We use Zookeeper to coordinate task execution among our clustered servers. One of our customers have a very instable network and our servers keep disconnecting and reconnecting to Zookeeper.

The problem is that while being disconnected, our servers will miss the events that occurred and won't handle them even after re-connecting to Zookeeper again.

- Is there a recommened\standard method to handle such situations using Zookeeper and Apache Curator ?
- How to identify the current epoch time at Zookeeper ?

My proposal so far is:

1. We keep track of the last time we were connected to Zookeeper. That's right before we get disconnected.
2. On re-connecting again, we ask the listener to [clearAndRefresh](https://curator.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/curator/framework/recipes/cache/PathChildrenCache.html#clearAndRefresh--) which fires **CHILD_ADDED** events for all child nodes for monitored path.
3. On handling these **CHILD_ADDED** events, we only handled those for paths that were created or modified after the last time we were connected to Zookeeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think using timestamp will be a good idea. Instead, you can use Curator's inbuilt:

- [TreeCache](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/tree-cache.html) if you want to watch an entire tree
- [PathChildrenCache](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/path-cache.html) if you want to watch only a sub directory.

It doesn't matter which one you use, both support listening to `ChildAdded` and `DataChanged` events which will do exactly what you need. When you reconnect after been disconnected, Curator will internally evaluate newly added children and compare data of existing children to determine changes. No pressure on you. You only need to use the listeners provided.

In terms of accuracy TreeCache is not guaranteeing 100% accuracy. So, you it is better if you can re-design you approach to use PathChildrenCache instead.